# Crystal Report problem when exporting report to PDF containing Arabic characters

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2017, arabic, export-to-pdf

I developed App with Visual Basic 2017 and crystal report
All works good until i export the report to PDF file
the problem is all Arabic words **that containing (لا)** displayed in separated letters
for example ..
this displayed in run time report (اسلام),
but after export to PDF file (ا س ل ا م),
However any other Arabic text **that doesn't containing (لا)** are displayed without any problem

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for this,
try to upgrade the crystal report to CRYSTAL REPORTS **Service Pack 24**
you can find the ver here:

https://www.tektutorialshub.com/crystal-reports/crystal-reports-download-for-visual-studio/

The Crystal Reports for Visual Studio is now known as Crystal Reports Developer Edition for Visual Studio. It is also known as CR for VS (CrforVs). Crystal Reports currently supports Visual Studio 2017, Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2012, Visual Studio 2010. Prior to Visual Studio 2010, the Crystal Reports were Installed along with Visual Studio.

I installed the latest ver Service Pack 24 and it works for me

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21933197)

Comment: @NicoHaase, the link that's been given is for downloading the service pack mentioned in the answer, there's not really a way to embed the service pack in the answer! =)

Comment: @Rob to me, that page does not even look like a primary source for such a download

Comment: @NicoHaase, it's not, but that's because trying to navigate the SAP website to find specific versions of Crystal Reports service packs is an exercise in abject horror =) There's a reason I have a OneNote page full of Crystal Reports direct download links and bookmarks for pages like the one the OP has linked to =)

Comment: I add some explanation hope this will make every one happy  @Nico Haase

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I've found: I don't export it anymore to PDF and use the CrystalReportViewer instead and Arabic words are ok.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this ...**

1. Run Crystal Report
2. Export Crystal Report

[image]